# Вывести 1000 знаков суммы ряда

Tags: c++, ряды

есть бесконечный ряд

```
ln(1+x) = x - (x^2)/2 + (x^3)/3 - (x^4)/4 + ...
```

Необходимо вычислить сумму с точностью до 1000 знаков.
Вот это то, до чего я смог дойти сам, но оно работает далеко не с 1000 знаками

```
long double  x, sum=0;
cin >> x;
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++){
    sum += (- pow(x,i)/i * pow(-1,i));
    cout <<  (- pow(x,i)/i * pow(-1,i)) <<endl;
}
cout << fixed;
cout.precision(1000);
cout << endl<<endl<<( sum);
```

Comment: Очевидно, что ни в какой `double` вы не влезете. Не менее очевидно, что нужна [длинная арифметика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)...

Comment: Для этой задачи нужно использовать библиотеку для работы с вещественными числами произвольной точности, например - GMP. Или свою написать.

Comment: @Harry далеко не факт. Иногда можно использовать спец формулы которые позволяют вычислить n-символ числа. учесть что формула оочень похожа на логарифм. А для логарифма есть такой способ.

Comment: @pavel Это и есть формула для ln(1+x), забыл указать

Comment: А в каком контексте дана эта задача?

Comment: @VladimirSW "в лоб вычисляется" плохо. Лучше использовать что-то с квадратичной сходимостью (формула Ньютона например).

Comment: @pavel Поделитесь, интересно...

Comment: @VTT Это и есть вся задача: просто вывести на экран 1000 знаков числа ln(1+x), в указании написано использовать этот ряд

Comment: если просто вывести - напишите длинную арифметику